# RecyclerView settle item with Decelerate Interpolator once scroll finishes

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to animate the `RecyclerView` scrolling. I don't want to animate adding or removal of items but rather animate items which are on screen, i.e visible items. What I want is, item settle down smoothly when scrolling is about to finish. I am not sure what approach should I take or how this can be done. I have tried following till now

- Using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`, when I get `onScrolled` callback, I find visible items & animate them upside or downside based on scroll direction. But this approach is no-where near to perfect & many times when scrolling fast, some visible views are null so animation doesn't apply on them & it looks weird.
- Tried to animate visible items when I receive `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`. But there's noticeable delay for a fraction of second when scrolling is finished & then items animate. It doesn't look natural
- Tried to figure out when `RecyclerView` scrolling is "about to" finish so I can start animation to mimic continuity of animation with scrolling. But didn't get success in identifying reliably that scrolling is about to finish.

Instead of above a little complex ways that doen't work the way I need, I wonder if there is any other way like creating custom `LayoutManager`where I can override the each item scrolling so that it settle to it's aimed position smoothly?

Edit: [Here's something very close to what I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588188/listview-item-scroll-animation-uikit-dynamics-like)

Comment: Show some pictures or animation/gif to understand what exactly you wanted.

Comment: @SagarShah please check now, I edited my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706013/2054348 check this if it can help you

Comment: @SagarShah this will only animate new items appearing & not the items already on screen.