# Animate UIView horizontally using UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicanimator

I have gone through the documentation, and I am embarrassed to say I am confused.

**The Scenario**:

I have a `UIView`, that acts like a container for 3 `UIButtons`. This container is initially of bounds `{0, 0, 35, 35}`, with each button inside with the same co-ordinates (with `alpha` 0). On a specific action by the user, the container changes bounds to `{0, 0, 100, 35}`, and the button are animated to x-origin 5, 35, and 65, respectively, with `alpha` 1, such that they are spread out inside the resized container. I refer to this as the *expanded state* of the container. The same action by the user, toggles it back to the original *contracted state*.

**The Goal**:

I am currently doing this using the `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` block, but would like to use the `UIDynamicAnimator` to add a bouncy effect, such that, when toggling to expanded state , the container resizes with a bounce (resizes a bit extra, and bounces back to target bounds), and the buttons bounce as well (move a bit further, and bounce back to their target bounds).

**The Confusion**:

`UIDynamicAnimator`, `UIDynamicBehavior`, `UIAttachmentBehavior`, `UIDynamicItem`.....all these are causing my understanding of `UIKitDynamic` to overflow. I think I should be using **`UISnapBehavior`** , but I do not know how to go about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, using `UIDynamicAnimator`, and all other *dynamic* animations was not needed. All I needed was the `animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations: completion:` class method. Just use it in place of any simple `animateWithDuration:` method, and it yields the exact behaviour i intended to achieve.

Sample code:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
          initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                        options:0
                     animations:^{

                         //Animation code

                     } completion:nil];
```